# When I delete a file from a separate partition, it does not go to Trash

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, delete, trash

I'm using Ubuntu in Dual boot with Windows 7. I have three partitions: one for Windows, one for Ubuntu, and one for my files (it is used in both OSs; let's call it D).

When I use Ubuntu and I delete a file from D, deleted files aren't going to Ubuntu trash (they are deleted directly). How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are referring to the Ubuntu trash and not windows?

Comment: Exactly ubuntu trash (if it was for windows I would say recycle bin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable Trash on Windows partition by making yourself its owner.

Find out your user id:

```
$ id
```

Open the fstab file, which holds partition mounting configuration:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Find your Windows partition (the one of ntfs type). It will look like this:

```
/dev/sda3 /home/user/shared    ntfs    defauls,noatime 0 0
```

(Note, that it doesn't have to be /dev/sda3, and the mount point and options may differ).

Add **uid=xxxx** to its list of options, where *xxxx* is your user ID:

```
/dev/sda3 /home/user/shared    ntfs    defauls,noatime,uid=xxxx 0 0
```

Save the fstab file and unmount/remount the Windows partition or simply reboot the computer. If it doesn't help, you might have to also add your group ID as **gid=yyyy**.

Taken from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345).

Answer (score 1):

Check permission:

```
cd  ~/.local/share/
ls  -la | grep Trash
```

If it says root then change the permission using:

```
sudo chown username:username Trash
```

Also, if you are using the `rm` command, then files are deleted permanently.